# Hibernate : Delete Many-to-Many association with join table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have two tables with the many-to-many association.

DB Details:
**User**--> Columns[Id,Name]

**Role**-->Columns[Id,Name]

**UserRoles**--> Columns[UserId,RoleId]

Hibernate Mapping Details:

```
/* User.hbm.xml */
<set name="Roles" table="UserRoles" inverse="true" cascade="all" lazy="false">
    <key column="UserId" />
    <many-to-many column="RoleId" class="Role" />
</set>
…
/* Rols.hbm.xml */
<join table="UserRoles">
    <key column="RoleId" />
    <many-to-one column="UserId" name="user"/>
</join>
```

When I am trying to delete the user, it is deleting the appropriate records in user and UserRoles, but it is also deleting Roles records which is not required using below code.

```
session.delete(user);
```

Even if I don't have any user in a Role, I want the Role to be there, just delete only records from User and UserRoles tables.How will i achieve this in XML.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of `cascade="all"` which includes REMOVE. Replace it according to what you really need. See [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/) for details.

Comment: could you please specified which is suitable to according above situation, I think its will be persist.

Comment: @Nitin I cannot say without knowing the application. In your place I 
 would start **without** cascade and only add it when required by a specific operation.